# Illuminate bottom of cube in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I illuminate the bottom of the cube?

Something like this:

[image: example]

Comment: thats a simple point light ABOVE the floor, not below.

Comment: I guess you'd like to make a cool effect with the lights coming from the bottom, right? The easiest solution would be creating an area light. Take a look at this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lighting.html